# Local XML file is not loading the local Image in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to save the image and xml file in plist. I can save it and changed the local image path in xml file.(Both image and the xml file in same folder in plist) Now i retrieve the xml file and load it in UIWebView but it could load all the values except the image. I need to load the image through the xml file in UIWebView.

Comment: Share some code and then paths of your resources in the bundle.

Comment: Check the xml path, the string path in that xml (need to do both if the path is relative), the image path with `pathForResource:ofType:` of `NSBundle`?

Comment: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9428C707-720B-4AC7-8A5A-D5C94140F36E/Documents/Images/2016-10-20_0-18-40.jpg.  Its my image path from the plist. My xml file path is /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9428C707-720B-4AC7-8A5A-D5C94140F36E/Documents/Images/test.xml.

Comment: I loading this xml file in webview  with <title>some xxxx</title><img src="local image path, which given in up" /><content>xxxxxxxxx</content>

Comment: the title and content are displaying fine. but the image is not loading.